# Get request for my Paypal AccessToken

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal

I am trying to get my access token of paypal.

I have the next parameters: `EndPoint`, `Client Id`, `secret`, `api username`, `api signature`, `api password`, `application Id`.

should I need a paypal client in order to do it?

I followed this link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/

and tried:

```
private string getAccessToken() {
    var ppClient; // = new paypalClient(); // create a paypal client

    Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    parameters.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    parameters.Add("Accept-Language", "en_US");
    parameters.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials");

    var result = ppClient.Get("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", parameters);

    string accessToken = result["access_token"];
    return accessToken;
}
```

thank you all!

Comment: So what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @mituw16, ppClient should be initialized..

Comment: In the code above, you commented out the part where you initialize the ppClient object.

Comment: I know, cause I don't know how to make a new client.. which parameters I have to define there? thank you!!

Comment: Take a look at this. https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sample-app-dotnet

Comment: Also. https://github.com/paypal/codesamples-dotnet

Answer (score 4):

I would recomend using RestSharp (just grab the NuGet package): -

```
        if (ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol != SecurityProtocolType.Tls12) ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; // forced to modern day SSL protocols
        var client = new RestClient(payPalUrl) { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
        var authRequest = new RestRequest("oauth2/token", Method.POST) {RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json};
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(clientId, secret);
        authRequest.AddParameter("grant_type","client_credentials");
        var authResponse = client.Execute(authRequest);
```

Comment: Fair point but quite a random negative comment to put against a question not related to security. Meanwhile what if you don't have direct access to the OS config (shared hosting, pre-configured containers or images, etc) or you want to run different security protocols on the same server but in different Web Apps (or even the same web app) because of 3rd party dependancies? Set it where you **need** to not where you are **told** to.

Comment: Really? PayPal tokens is all about how you set the Security Protocol? I said "fair point" and read the Microsoft documention, the least you could do is take my comments on board and add to the discussion instead of just re-making the same point. All I was doing is trying to help someone, the Microsoft docs assume you have full control of the server config "The recommended solution in all cases above is to remove the hardcoded protocol version selection and defer to the operating system default" what if the OS default is wrong and you can't change it?

Answer (score 0):

Came to this a little late, but ran into similar problem.  In the end I had to use a "Basic" authentication implementation to get the details back from PayPal. This is my Token Collector class.  The Only thing you really need to do is substitute my PayPal options injection with your 2 paypal client_Id and Secret strings generated in your paypal set up.

Ignore my AccessToken return type, its just a PoCo I made up and the ReadToObject is just a simple deserializer using newtonsoft. 
The real good stuff is returned to the 'result' string.

Hope this helps!

```
    public sealed class PaymentTokenServer : IPaymentTokenServer
{
    private readonly List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> tokenServerPairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    private PayPalOptions payPalOptions;

    public PaymentTokenServer(IOptions<PayPalOptions> paypalOptions)
    {
        this.payPalOptions = paypalOptions.Value;

       this.tokenServerPairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"));
    }

    public AccessToken GetToken()
    {
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(this.tokenServerPairs);
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(this.payPalOptions.TokenServerUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.Add( new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("en_US"));

            var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{this.payPalOptions.ClientId}:{this.payPalOptions.Secret}"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64String);

            var response = client.PostAsync("", content).Result;

            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            return result.ReadToObject<AccessToken>();
        }
    }
}
```